# How to resend simplenews content for many times - Simplenews module

Tags: emails

I use drupal 7 and simplenews module.I want to send a simplenews for several times.by default simple news module support onetime send to user.but i want to send simplenews to user for several times by UI . 
Is any way for resending support in simplenews module ?

Is any other module for edit contents before sending by mail and send it for several times to subscribers?

Comment: I solved my problem with use simplenes_content_selection module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:
[simplenews Status Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_status_reset) module .

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue for Drupal 8. I created a module to do this:
https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_resend

This module adds a reset status link to the newsletter operations.